# How do I set the hotkey Print to Rectangular Region in Spectacle?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde

For the Kde Spectacle Tool, I want to set the hotkey Print to replace Meta+Shift+Print for a rectangular region screenshot.

For reference: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdegraphics/spectacle/starting.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on Kubuntu 18.04. This answer is based on Kubuntu 18.04.

Open `System Settings` > `Shortcuts` > `Custom Shortcuts`.

[image: System Settings]

In there, click on the arrow-head, circled in red, to the left of `Screenshots` to see the available default actions.

[image: Screenshot actions]

You'll see that `Print` starts the screenshot tool

[image: Print action]

and that `Meta+Shift+Print` takes a screenshot of a rectangular area

[image: Rectangular selection]

Now, to use `Print` to take a rectangular screenshot area, you first need to free up the `Print` key.

To do so,

- go back to `Start Screenshot Tool`
- click on the `Trigger` tab
- click within the the box next to `Shortcut`
- then simultaneously press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>
- click `Apply` in the lower right corner of the window.

Next, re-assign the trigger for `Take Rectangular Region Screenshot` the same way but just press the `PrintScreen` key and click `Apply`.

Now, whenever you press the `PrintScreen` key, you'll be prompted to select a rectangular area.

[image: Using PrintScreen key to take a rectangular area screenshot]

Comment: Yeah, I am on Kubuntu shown on the tag so I thought it was redundant if I stated it again in the body.

Comment: @QuanDo Notice I also mentioned the version. A lot changes from version to version. Just "Kubuntu" isn't enough. Next time, please mention the version as well somewhere. It would be helpful to people trying to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Kubuntu 16.04 doesn' t have this option?

Comment: @xgdgsc I'm sorry, I no longer have access to 16.04 and so can't answer your query.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays Spectacle shortcuts are directly in *Global Shortcuts* rather than in *Custom Shortcuts*.

[image]

But the other configuration steps stay nearly the sames

Comment: I don't know which version you're on, but Kubuntu 19.04 with Plasma 5.16.5 still has the Screenshot shortcuts under Custom Shortcuts.

Comment: I have Plasma 5.16.4 and spectacle 19.08.0

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu 21.10 and KDE 5.22.5 I removed all shortcuts and add a custom for waiting to select.

[image]