# What is the KDE equivalent of the Microsoft Windows Alt+Space and Alt+'-' sequences?

Tags: shortcut-keys, plasma-5

Microsoft Windows enables you to activate a window's system menu using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key combination and do so for an internal window ie (MDI) via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> combinations. It is equivalent to clicking the icon on the application's title bar to activate the menu.

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> in KDE, the KRunner dialogue (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>) pops up.

Does KDE have an equivalent for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and if not how can I change the mapping from KRunner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike many other desktop environments, KDE Plasma doesn't use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> as the default keyboard combination to bring up the client window menu to which you refer. One has to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> or one can click on the `Menu` button (circled) usually at the top left of the window's titlebar:

[image: Alt+F3 or menu button]

If you wish to change things, you can via `Custom Shortcuts`. I've have [an answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079683/248158) that describes changing shortcuts which you may find helpful.

I'm not going into specifics because keyboard shortcuts are a matter of personal choice and they also depend on what other shortcuts you have set up or intend to set up in the future.

Comment: For other desktops see https://askubuntu.com/a/1073932/66509 .