# zbrush 2020, Wine, and Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, wine, kde

I have [zbrush 2020](https://pixologic.com/features/) running with Wine on Kubuntu 19.10. It is working well. One issue... the keyboard commands are not exactly correct. Instead of just pushing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, I have to push <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. Not a crazy big deal but I am wondering if there is a fix for that or if I installed something wrong.

Comment: If you didn't run into any other problems, except for the Alt key, then that's great news. There are some other issues regarding pressure sensitivity, file handling, GoZ etc. You can find that information here: https://www.zbrushcentral.com/t/using-zbrush-on-linux/351246/48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no description in the listing for [zbrush 2020 at the WineHQ database of apps](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=38459) so you appear to be the first report. However, KDE does not perfectly [copy the conventions of other desktops](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084340/what-is-the-kde-equivalent-of-the-microsoft-windows-altspace-and-alt-sequen) with respect to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, so you may wish to ask in [KDE specialty web sites](https://forum.kde.org/search.php).

Comment: I had a feeling I was going to need to ask the kde community. I checked the WineHQ database as well. I did not find anything. I was hoping someone here had been through the same thing. Hoping there was an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could check that the Alt key is not already assigned by the operating system. On XFCE4 it is by default assigned to move windows, and then it will not work in ZBrush Wine. When it is not assigned to anything it works in ZBrush.