# Assigning global short cut to take a screenshot of a rectangular area and copy it to clipboard

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, screenshot

I would like to create a global shortcut to take a screenshot of a rectangular region and assign it to <kbd>Printscreen</kbd> as done in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079626/how-do-i-set-the-hotkey-print-to-rectangular-region-in-spectacle) question. The problem is, that this option apparently only is available under 18.04 while I am using 16.04. Does anyone know how to achieve the same thing under 16.04?

Comment: Kubuntu 16.04 is no longer supported. If possible, install Kubuntu 18.04 LTS or switch to Ubuntu 16.04 which will be supported until 2021.

Comment: @DKBose If that was possible, I would have done so a long time ago. Unfortunately I can‘t influence the OS choices that our linux admins male at work.

Comment: Well, I no longer have Kubuntu 16.04 and so can't help!

Comment: @DKBose I saw that in your answer to that other guys colment already. That‘s why I opened this question. Thanks anyway